# flight delayed from London Heathrow to Grand Cayman

Tags: air-travel

actual flight times BA0253 on 22 may2016 heathrow to George town cayman islands as flight delayed

Answer (score 1):

From [flightstats historical flight status](http://www.flightstats.com/go/HistoricalFlightStatus/flightStatusByFlight.do):
BA253 Scheduled gate departure 10:25, actual 14:01
Scheduled gate arrival NAS 14:45, actual 18:39 (late 239 minutes)

Scheduled gate departure NAS 15:45, actual 19:26
Scheduled gate arrival GCM 16:20, actual 19:46 (late 206 minutes)